# To make Smart Priority for Dropbox File Sync

Tags: sync, dropbox

I tweeted this idea already and put some peer-pressure to the developers of Dropbox.

**Is there any possibility to put some Smart Priority for Syncing files in Dropbox?**
I want to sync first files in Public -directory, because my clients are waiting.

Answer (score 0):

No. 
The developers have no motivation and skills to do this. 
They have severe problems in syncing files through many users. 
Option is to move to Bittorent sync which has much potential to knock out Dropbox from their position (many times faster download and upload); minus side is that you have to have your server or your computer online to enable the data transfer; so not complete substitute. 
At least, I will stop by Dropbox Pro and its paid addons after a year.